# How can I enter multiple values into a vector field at the same time?

Tags: interface

I'm wondering if there isn't an easy way to enter multiple values into a vector field at the same time, instead of filling in all the input fields individually.

How does this work?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Left click on the top or bottom value, keep the left click pressed, drag down or up, type the value:

[image]

Also a node that may save you time sometimes is the *Input > Value*:

[image]

Comment: Simple question, competent and quick answer! Very fine, I could not find this question/answer here on BSE yet ;-)

Comment: You're welcome, also sometimes if your node has an input you can use the Input > Value node